# What are the DLCs?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I have the following issue. I like the Elder Scrolls Online, played it while it was with subscription, fun and all. Anyway, I take a break and it is free now, but I see it has a premium upgrade (basically the same as the subscription) with details [here](http://www.elderscrollsonline.com/en-us/news/post/2015/01/21/your-guide-to-eso-plus-premium-membership).

I can live without the 10% bonus xp and the crowns, but I want to play the whole content since I like the stories. My problem is that I can't find anything about the dlcs. Absolutely anything. So anyone played them? Are they a mission? A group of missions? When will I encounter them, etc?

So can anyone point me towards a place with some details? If they published them on E.S.O site, they hide them pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now (end of May 2015) there aren't any DLCs released so far, since Zenimax Online Studios wanted to release the game on consoles first, then start releasing DLCs (which they've been working on since last year).

So far there's no information available regarding prices, but they've already said, they'd release more information as well as a roadmap soon (i.e. at E3 2015), which will start in about two weeks.

However, since a subscription will also net you crowns to spend (the same amount as if you'd be purchasing the 15 $/€ package once a month), you can also subscribe now and use those bonus crowns later on to buy finished DLC.

The first DLC to be released will be access to the Imperial City, although they haven't stated whether that content would be free for all or indeed be the first DLC (since it's connected to the PvP/AvA endgame).

Comment: So basically, atm there is no difference regarding content between premium account and normal one?

Comment: @zozo Correct, only difference/bonus is the bonus XP/AP/Gold/etc. right now.